# prop number won't change the time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm building an audio player with basic functionalities like backward, play and forward button. The player does the backward functionality fine but the forward doesn't work even though I set the same variable for both. What could be the reason for this anomaly?

```
props: {
    skipTime: {
        type: Number
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prev() {
      this.$refs.audio.currentTime -= this.skipTime;
    },
    next(){
      this.$refs.audio.currentTime += this.skipTime;
    }
```

however this works

```
props: {
    skipTime: {
        type: Number
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prev() {
      this.$refs.audio.currentTime -= this.skipTime;
    },
    next(){
      this.$refs.audio.currentTime += 5;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `this.skipTime` is set? Sounds like it's not.

Comment: sorry, yeah there was a typo there. however I set the same skipTime for both backward and forward and only the backward works, the forward doesn't work. can prop be set only one time? @MarkReed

Comment: I assume you have the close braces in your actual code..

Comment: yes I have those @MarkReed

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `this.$refs.audio.currentTime += this.skipTime;` is doing string concatenation instead of sum, try out :

```
  this.$refs.audio.currentTime += +this.skipTime;
```

,

```
 this.$refs.audio.currentTime += Number(this.skipTime);
```

or

```
this.$refs.audio.currentTime =Number(this.$refs.audio.currentTime )+ Number(this.skipTime);
```